# Как достать файл .bin из документа .doc

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

если поменять расширение документа.doc  на архив (.zip .rar), то можно увидеть что он из себя представляет файловое хранилище. Необходимо достать из него файл .bin как это сделать программно?

Comment: использовать библиотеки, которые работают с OpenXML и *.docx форматом?

Comment: вы случаем не путаете .doc и .docx?

Comment: @user7860670 у формата .doc есть поддержка макросов, его и нужно достаь

Comment: @tym32167 а может можете дать пример кода?

Comment: формат .doc бесполезно переименовывать в архив

Answer (score 2):

Видимо, все же имеется в виду `.docm` - файл Word с поддержкой макросов.

```
unzip file.docm *.bin
```

отлично распакует `.bin`-файл, буде такой будет иметься. Если не нужна структура подкаталогов - то

```
unzip -j file.docm *.bin
```